# How to Set Gihub Secret with a Binary File for Github Workflow?

Tags: github, binary, github-actions, binaryfiles

I would like to add one of my API configuration file (`binary.file`) to the Github secret (MY_BINARY_SECRET). Then it will be read and wrote to `binary.file` again in the workflow:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install System
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y pip python3.8-venv libcurl4-openssl-dev

      - name: Set up configurations
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.MY_BINARY_SECRET }}" > binary.file
          python3 .... # the python script will need binary.file to complete authentication
```

However, I tried many hours with different ways to copy the binary content to the Github Secret, but all failed. I tried `pbcopy`, `less`, `cat`. Does anyone know how to write a binary file via Github Secret in the github actions? Or a better solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Encode `MY_BINARY_SECRET` to base64 and decode it back to `binary.file`.

Comment: @phd Thanks for answering! Would you be able to provide an exmaple?

Comment: `echo "$MY_BINARY_SECRET" | base64 -w0 >secret.b64` . Upload text file `secret.b64` as the secret to GitHub. Decode it using `echo -n "${{ secrets.MY_BINARY_SECRET }}" | base64 -d > binary.file` (first try it locall).

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Extending my comment):

Use [`base64`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) to encode binary string to text and decode it back to binary. This is pretty standard trick.

First, encode at home:

```
echo "$MY_BINARY_SECRET" | base64 --wrap=0 > secret.b64
```

`--wrap=0` to make the output text one long line; useful for `echo` below.

Upload text file `secret.b64` as the secret to GitHub. Decode it using

```
echo -n "${{ secrets.MY_BINARY_SECRET }}" | base64 --decode > binary.file
```

Advice: first try decoding locally and compare with the original string. Must be the same.